# Problema com a altura de imagem quadrada dentro de div retangular

Tags: css, css3

tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<style>
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 42px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
div img {
  width: 50%;
}
</tyle>

<div>
      <img src=''>
</div>
```

**O problema**: Essa **imagem** é *quadrada* e a **div** *retangular*.

Como faço para que a **imagem** ***NÃO*** fique com a **altura errada** dentro **div** ? Isto é, deixe de ficar **quadrada** por causa do `width: 50%`?

Já tentei `height: auto` na **imagem** mas não deu certo!

Já tentei `max-width: 50%;`na **imagem** mas também não deu certo!

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer. Poderia colocar um exemplo de como está agora e como quer que fique?

Comment: Qual é o tamanho que você quer que a imagem fique dentro da div ? No caso qual a altura e qual a largura com relação a div...

Comment: Sim, Imagem quadrada, div (containner), retangular. Na hora que faço na img width: 50% ele meio que leva o height da imagem junto e a magim acaba ficando distorcida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não espero que vc entenda o problema, sério mesmo, acho muito pouco provável que vc vá entender o que ocorre, mas basicamente é por causa do `padding` que vc usou no *container* pai, esse `padding` acaba influenciando no filho que tem valores em `%`.

Esse valores de `padding` do pai acabam "se somando" aos valores em `%` dos filhos, já que o `padding` sempre se soma  ao `box-model`, assim como as `bordas` tb se somam a largura/altura total do elemento, a não ser que vc diga ao contrário, como explico abaixo.

Para resolver basta que vc colocar `box-sizing: border-box;` para o valor do padding não mudar o tamanho do `box-model`, ou então vc não usar `padding` no pai e usar `margins` no filho, como fiz nos exemplos abaixo.

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

div img {
    width: 50%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div style="box-sizing: border-box;">
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100">
    <br>
    com box-sizing
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100">
    <br>
    sem box-sizing
</div>
<div style="padding: 0;">
    <img style="margin: 5px" src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100">
    <br>
    sem padding no pai<br>
    com margin no filho
</div>
```

Comment: entendi muto bem tua resposta.  meu erro estava em que ao invés de colocar border-box, havia colocado content-box. Passei para border box e deu certo, Novamente, meu muito obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosRocha que o border-box resolve fica claro, difícil é perceber que o padding do pai afeta o filho, essa é uma das bizarrisses do CSS,mas que bom que resolveu

Comment: Sim,vai afetar pois se a div é content-box (padrão), logo o padding aumentaria a altura da div em desproporcionalidade com a altura da imagem uma vez que a imagem é quadrada e a div retangular. Se ambas fosses quadradas, logo não daria esse problema! Entendi correto? Por outro lado, com border-box, a borda passa a ser o limite!